# TextFormField is responsive for typing, but after capturing an image, it becomes unresponsive

Tags: flutter, windows

I am currently developing a Windows application with Flutter, and I have a situation where the TextFormField is responsive for typing, but after capturing an image, it becomes unresponsive. can someone help me?? iam using this lib file_picker: 6.1.1

i want to typing text in textform field even after pick image